# SQL Server 2012 Function "Percentile_Cont" - GROUP BY issue

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reporting, percentile

I have been trying to calculate the 50th percentile of a field all day and I think I am getting close, but I am a little stuck.

This is the normal code, without `percentile_cont`:

```
declare @st_date datetime;
declare @en_date datetime;
declare @days int;

set @en_date = (@en_datein);
set @st_date = (@st_datein);

select 
    srt.Name,
    cast(sum(sr.price) as int) as AvgCost,
    cast(sum(sr.cost) as int) as AvgTransCost,
    cast(avg(sr.TotalTimeSpent) as int) as TotalTimeSpent
from 
    ServiceReq sr, ServiceReqTemplate srt
where 
    sr.SvcReqTmplLink_RecID = srt.RecId
    and sr.CreatedDateTime >= @st_date
    and sr.CreatedDateTime <= @en_date
group by 
    srt.Name
order by 
    1
```

This is my code when I add `percentile_cont`:

```
declare @st_date datetime;
declare @en_date datetime;
declare @days int;

set @en_date = (@en_datein);
set @st_date = (@st_datein);

SELECT srt.Name,
    percentile_cont(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sr.price) OVER(PARTITION BY srt.Name) AS MedianSpend,
    cast(sum(sr.price) as int) as AvgCost,
    cast(sum(sr.cost) as int) as AvgTransCost,
    cast(avg(sr.TotalTimeSpent) as int) as TotalTimeSpent
from 
    ServiceReq sr, ServiceReqTemplate srt
where 
    sr.SvcReqTmplLink_RecID = srt.RecId
    and sr.CreatedDateTime >= @st_date
    and sr.CreatedDateTime <= @en_date
group by 
    srt.Name
order by 
    1
```

If I try and execute this I receive the error:

> Column sr.price is invalid in the select list because is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I have googled this error and have been reading up on StackOverFlow but I have yet to solve this issue. I tried adding a second Group By, but I'm confused as to which variable I'm supposed to use or if I am even doing this correctly!!

How do I make the percentile_cont code work with the cast code under the same Select statement??

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: its an out of the box report that I am customizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it will give you the desired output or not but it will fix the error.
try with this

```
percentile_cont(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sum(sr.price)) OVER(PARTITION BY srt.Name) AS MedianSpend
```

Complete statement

```
declare @st_date datetime;
declare @en_date datetime;
declare @days int;

set @en_date = (@en_datein);
set @st_date = (@st_datein);

SELECT srt.Name,
    percentile_cont(.5) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sum(sr.price)) OVER(PARTITION BY srt.Name) AS MedianSpend,
    cast(sum(sr.price) as int) as AvgCost,
    cast(sum(sr.cost) as int) as AvgTransCost,
    cast(avg(sr.TotalTimeSpent) as int) as TotalTimeSpent
from 
    ServiceReq sr, ServiceReqTemplate srt
where 
    sr.SvcReqTmplLink_RecID = srt.RecId
    and sr.CreatedDateTime >= @st_date
    and sr.CreatedDateTime <= @en_date
group by 
    srt.Name
order by 
    1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am able to run it, but I am unable to display the Median still.

Comment: say I didn't want the sum(sr.price), and instead only wanted ORDER BY (sr.price), how can I accomplish that without receiving an aggregate function error.